# Django ModelAdmin queryset override doesn't work

Tags: django-admin, overriding, django-queryset

I'm trying to override the queryset() of a ModelAdmin class so that the list of objects shown in admin would be sorted **by two levels**.

I've tried the following code, but it does not work, i.e. the table is not sorted as expected

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ProductAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.order_by('category','market')

    list_display = ('category', 'market', 'name', 'quantity')

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

btw, you can't use `ordering = ('category','market')` as django specifically states that only the first item in the ordering tuple takes effect (see note in the documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#multiple-sort-in-admin-interface) for Django 1.4 say that Django now supports `Multiple sort in admin interface`:

> The admin change list now supports sorting on multiple columns. It
>   respects all elements of the ordering attribute, and sorting on
>   multiple columns by clicking on headers is designed to mimic the
>   behavior of desktop GUIs.

And from [ModelAdmin ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering):

> Set `ordering` to specify how lists of objects should be ordered in the
>   Django admin views. This should be a list or tuple in the same format
>   as a model's `ordering` parameter. [...] Django honors **all elements** in the list/tuple; before 1.4, only the first was respected.

On a semi-related note - if you do override `queryset` to provide a custom sort order, it seems that the `Changelist` will override that sort order. It applies any sorting found in the `ordering` parameter, and if there isn't one, it applies a default sort by `pk`, thus negating any sorting you did in `queryset`.

I *think* it's supposed to work - at least this [Django Ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7309) says *fixed*. But I was just trying to apply a custom sort using `queryset` a few days ago, and it didn't work at all for me. Even sorting on a single field, seemed to be overridden in the final view. So either I did something wrong, or it's not all that fixed. :)

Note that it *is* possible to do a custom sort via code, but you have to subclass `Changelist`, and override its `get_query_set()` method, as per [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2110/). (Although this is overkill, if you only need multiple fields sorted, since Django 1.4 now supports multiple fields).

Answer (score 8):

`get_queryset` works in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exactly problem. Here's what I did:

I subclassed `ChangeList` and overrode `ChangeList.get_query_set` to redo the correct order_by that was previously changed by `ChangeList.get_ordering`:

This is what I did in my case (I'm using django-easytree, but the same applies for django-mptt):

```
class MyChangeList(ChangeList):

    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(MyChangeList, self).get_query_set()

        return qs.order_by('tree_id', 'lft')
```

Also, check these tickets:

- ["NFA: Don't override order_by if no default ordering is specified"](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7309)
- ["Admin ChangeList doesn't apply 'order_by' clause specified by ModelAdmin.queryset"](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10212)

Comment: Wow that's a 3 year old ticket that's still marked as "new". Seems like a design bug to me...

Comment: @Jonathan: agreed and a very frustrating bug.